# Как перенести инфу String

Tags: java, строки, null

Добрый день допустим у меня есть

```
     String noom = null; 
     String noom1 = "hydroelectric";
```

И мне нужно перенести значение num1 в num каким методом и как вообще это можно сделать?

Comment: num=num1 ... или что ты имеешь ввиду под словом перенести?

Comment: @Upiter 1401 В Java, String immutable(неизменяемый). Что значит перенести? Читай [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-pool) однако.

Comment: Чтобы значение noom было такое же как noom1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот я сделал
 `noom = noom1;`